# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes on my Dell

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Since few hours, my system freezes aproximatey every 30min. I checked `xsession-errors` and 'Script for ibus started at run_im.' is written there. 
Any idea what might cause the problem and how to fix it?
The output of: "lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0653
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0653
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: done, you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if this solves the problem. Btw, why does this problem appear now? I have this computer since few months.